# storing the selected date on bootstrap 3 date time picker with meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, meteor

I am using bootstrap 3 date time picker in a meteor application. I am trying to store the selected date so I can use it later. Currently just trying to show the selected date in console. When I run my program I have no errors in my log, however it is also not showing the selected date in the log. Here are my codes
HTML

```
<template name="teetimepicker">

<div class="input-group datetimepicker">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
<input class="set-due-date form-control" type="text"/>
</div>

</template>
```

.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
 Template.teetimepicker.onRendered(function() {
 this.$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
 });


function dateSelection(){
var selectedDate = $("#datetimepicker").data("datetimepicker").getDate();
console.log(selectedDate);
 };
```

Again I have no console errors but nothing in the log. I need to store the selected date per each user. Thank You for any help!

Comment: You are not calling your`dateSelection()` function anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an event attached to your `teetimepicker` template, handling the date change in your date picker. It could look like that:

```
Template.teetimepicker.events({
  "changeDate #datetimepicker": function(event, template) {
      console.log(event.currentTarget.)//whatever you need
  }
});
```